# Saving Json into DB with Spring framework

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I save Json String into DB:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < callSubSetJson.size(); i++) {
        CallDto c = new CallDto();
        c.setCallsJ(callSubSetJson.get(i));
        _callRepository.save(c);
    }
```

and it is saved in format like this:

`[{\"number\":\"0005\",\"name\":\"whoewer :)\",\"id\":3377,\"date\":\"14385113015...etc`

when I return that to client I have to do some clean up, remove all the `\`.

I believe that this is not the most efficient way to do it. What is the correct and efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonEncoder.encode(result); this will remove all .

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this you need the [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) library (I used version `1.1.1`); and this is how it may look like:

```
final String data = "[{\"number\":\"0005\",\"name\":\"whoewer :)\",\"id\":3377,\"date\":\"14385113015\"}]";
final Object obj = JSONValue.parse(data);
final JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;

System.out.printf("%s%n", array);
```

Output

```
[{"date":"14385113015","number":"0005","name":"whoewer :)","id":3377}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various choices to d so. Yoi can either use JSONENCODE, StringTokenize or any regex to do it.